# Declare a variable value during running Java RMI server

Tags: java, server, client, rmi

I am new in Java RMI and trying to do some learning in different condition. I don't know what I am trying to do is appropriate or not. So far I have developed an RMI application where client gives an input & get the factorial for that. I have 4 class for the application.

Those along with code are following.

Server class - FacServer

```
import java.rmi.*;
public class FacServer
{
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
{
    FacImpl obj = new FacImpl();
    Naming.rebind("FAC",obj);
    System.out.println("Server started");
}
}
```

Client class - FacClient

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public class FacClient
{
public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
{
  FacInt obj = (FacInt)Naming.lookup("FAC");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
  String s = null;
  try {
     s = br.readLine();
  } catch(IOException ioe) {
     System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
  }
    int r = Integer.parseInt(s);
    int n= obj.fac(r);

    System.out.println("Factorial is "+n);
}
}
```

Implementation class  - FacImpl

```
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class FacImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FacInt 
{
public FacImpl() throws Exception
{
    super();
}
public int fac(int x)
{
int i,j=1;
for(i=x;i>1;i--)
j=j*i;
return j;
}
}
```

Interface class - FacInt

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
public interface FacInt extends Remote
{
public int fac(int x) throws Exception;
}
```

It works fine. Now I want to set some limitation in server side. For example server won't calculate the factorial value for more than 5. I know I can do it in implementation class easily. But I want to declare it when I start the server. For example to set limitation 5 I should start the server in following way.

Java FacServer 5

So if client input a value more than 5 it will get an error reply. Is it possible to do so?

Also can I show the factorial value in server side also if client provide an accepted value?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use java System.properties in server side like

```
java FacServer -Dlimit="5"
```

and inside your java class you can fetch it like below and put your logic.

```
int limit=Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("limit"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Can I show the factorial value in server side also?

Comment: Yes. Usually in RMI ,you should  write your business logic in server side code only and client side code is written to find the Server using RMIInterface Object that looks for a reference for the remote object associated with the name we pass as parameter.